# Replacing Values with Blanks in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I've found some solutions with cells but none with Numberarrays.

The Problem is simple, I have one `Array a=(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7)` and I want to change every other value with "blankspace" like this `a=(0,'',2,''...)` so that the array stays the same length but has only every other value.

When I try something like this `a(2:2:end)='';` 
I get `a=(0,2,4,6)` the length is not the same.

When I try `a(2:2:end)=blanks(1);`
 
It almost works :), but not exactly, I get `a=(0,'32',2,'32',4,'32'...)`

I know that actually 32 means 'space' (ASCII) what actually means it works properly. I then try to use this to set my TickLabels but it interprets it like 32 not like ASCII.

Comment: what exactly is your objective? i.e. why can't you use cell arrays if it works for setting XTick labels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't introduce a space as an entry in a number array. You can only introduce numbers.

If you want that for using it as tick labels, convert to a cell array and then you can set some cells' contents to `[]` (empty):

```
a = [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7]; % original vector
a = num2cell(a); % convert to cell
a(2:2:end) = {[]}; % set some cells' contents to []

x = 1:8; % x data for example plot
y = x.^2; % y data for example plot
plot(x, y) % x plot the graph
set(gca, 'xticklabels', a) % set x tick labels
```

[image]

To get tick labels without scientific notation use `num2str` with the appropriate format:

```
a = [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7]*1e6; % original vector
a = num2cell(a); % convert to cell
a(2:2:end) = {[]}; % set some cells' contents to []
a = cellfun(@num2str, a, 'Uniformoutput', false); % convert each number to a string

x = [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7]*1e6; % x data for example plot
y = x.^2; % y data for example plot
plot(x, y) % x plot the graph
set(gca, 'xticklabels', a) % set x tick labels
```

Comment: Yep, i got it now, when i read the TickLabel it is a Cell, but the Ticks themselvs are Double Arrays i saw it now. Thank you very much for the support. Small question i read the Ticks:
a=ax1.XTick;  % a [100000,200000,300000,400000,...,1000000]
a = num2cell(a);
a(2:2:end) = {[]};
ax1.XTickLabel=a;
then i get the plot almost right the 1 000 000 is shown as 1e+06, i don't get it, i thought cells are strings of chars not of numbers :).

Comment: I tried this way ax1.TickLabelInterpreter='none';
 but still 1e+06.

Comment: @GDD Try `a = cellfun(@num2str, a, 'Uniformoutput', false);` (see edit)

Comment: @GDD Glad I could help!